# Phone number. Third character should be NOT 5 or 6 but should still be a digit 0-9

Tags: regex

This is just a learning exercise.

[image]

I want to match the first two phone numbers. But not the last 3.

In the last one you have a letter as the 3rd character.

`[\d]{3}[^56][\d]{5}`

This would select the ones without 5 or 6. 
But it would also select the last one with "D".
How do I solve this this?

There is no AND operator in REGEX as far as I know.

`[\d]{3}([[^56]&[\d])[\d]{5}`  <- Doesn't exist

Comment: How about `[0-47-9]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce a positive look ahead after consuming three characters to ensure the next character is a digit with this regex,

```
\b[\d]{3}(?=\d)[^56][\d]{5}\b
         ^^^^^^
```

This lookahead will first ensure the character has to be a digit and will reject the match if it is either `5` or `6`

**[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/h6OBCr/1)**

Another way to solve it would be to use `[0-47-9]` instead of `[^56]` and use this regex instead,

```
\b[\d]{3}[0-47-9][\d]{5}\b
```

**[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/h6OBCr/2)**